# can use $(document).ready inside window.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use defer attribute and now i should use for internal script this code :

`window.addEventListener('load', function () { // mycode }`

Now my old code like this :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#favBtn').on('click',function(){
            //mycode
        });
     });
</script>
```

I have question . Should i use `$(document).ready` inside `window.addEventListener` or i don't need `$(document).ready` when i use `window.addEventListener` ?

Is it true this code :

```
<script>
     window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#favBtn').on('click',function(){
                //mycode
            });
         });
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` just says jquery is ready to rock.. You could probably use it there and be ok but really you just could get by with wrapping your code in it and all will be well..

Comment: @Rick: `$(document).ready` says nothing about jQuery. It’s about the document.

Comment: It’s redundant to have `$(document).ready` inside `window.addEventListener('load',` but why do you need `window.addEventListener` in the first place? Most of the usual things are possible in `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Well correction then.. doc ready says the dom is ready, which includes any usage of jQuery..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).ready()` will execute right after the HTML document is loaded property, and the DOM is ready. The `window.addEventListener('load', function () { // mycode }` however will wait for the page to be fully loaded, this includes inner frames, images etc. So you need not write `$(document).ready()` inside `window.load`

In order to write jquery `$(document).ready()` by itself is sufficient

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do after dom ready you can try this below.

```
window.addEventListner("domContentLoad",function(){
//Your code
}
```

Comment: The name of the event is `DOMContentLoaded`, for one.

Comment: @bharat your answer not helpfull